# Filter pandas data frame for col == None

Tags: python, pandas, subset, data-cleaning

I have a data frame `data_df` with multiple columns, one of which is `c` which holds country names. How do I filter out the rows where `c == None`.

My first attempt was to do this:

```
countries_df = data_df[data_df.c != None]
```

However, that yielded 0 rows. This, however, worked:

```
countries_df = data_df[~data_df.c.isin([None])]
```

Can someone explain why? It seems that from the Pandas doc, the first should be able to filter correctly.

Some sample rows:

```
  _heartbeat_                           a                    al     c      cy     g
0   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; H...   en-US   US  Anaheim 15r91
1   NaN Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT ...   en-us   None    NaN ifIpBW
2   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20...   en-US,en;q=0.5  US  Fort Huachuca   10DaxOu
3   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; S...   en-US   US  Houston TysVFU
4   NaN Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/7.5.33286/29.3...   en  None    NaN 10IGW7m
5   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT...   en-US   US  Mishawaka   13GrCeP
6   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) G...   en-US,en;q=0.5  US  Hammond YmtpnZ
7   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_5 li...   en-us   None    NaN 13oM0hV
8   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like ...   en-us   AU  Sydney  15r91
9   NaN Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKi...   en-US,en;q=0.8  None    NaN 109LtDc
10  NaN Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like ...   en-us   US  Middletown  109ar5F
11  NaN Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like ...   en-us   US  Germantown  107xZnW
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I added some sample rows above.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It appears that pandas and Numpy treat `None` specially when comparing for equality.  In pandas, `None` is supposed to be like NaN, representing a missing value.  To find rows where the value is not None (or `nan`), you could do `data_df[data_df.c.notnull()]` (or `data_df[~data_df.c.isnull()]`).

Comment: slightly more readable to use `notnull` so `data_df[data_df.c.notnull()]`

Answer (score 0):

Using dropna() should also work:

```
countries_df = data_df.dropna(subset = 'c')
```